# How to check if i/ostream is empty?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to write a simple function that will pause my console.

Simple enough, but I want it to work in both cases: when the stream is empty, you just use `std::cin.get();` or `std::getchar();`; and when the stream is not empty, if you have inputted anything during the course of the program, you would have to use `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n'); std::cin.get();`;

So, I wanna write a function which would handle both with a simple `if` statement, if possible. Unfortunately I'm insanely bad with C++ `streams`. I hope someone with more knowledge in the area can help or point out the obvious function I've missed. Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

void pause()
{
    if (std::cin.eof()) //I don't know what I'm doing here. Don't judge, lol
    {
        std::cin.get();
    }
    else
    {
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cin.get();
    }
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    std::cin >> i;          //if I comment this line, I would have to press enter twice
    std::cout << "Hello world!";                         //to close the console
    pause();
}
```

Comment: have a look at this: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/90228/flushing-the-input-stream.  It gets into pausing at the end.

Comment: _"I don't know what I'm doing here."_ That's most probably your problem. `std::cin.eof()` is unlikely to become true.

Comment: You wanna ignore till `EOF`, not `\n`.

Comment: Thanks, NathanOliver! I managed to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void pause()
{
    if (std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail() > 0)
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Some explanation? :)